# Sending Html table data by ajax to php page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am using laravel framework, I have one index page in that I am retrieving dynamic table from another page by ajax(using div). Then now I am allowing user to edit table values so now I want to send modified table data to next php to process some actions on those values. So how can take those modified table values and how to send it to next php page by ajax or php script. And how can I assign those ajax values to php varriables.[Here is the snapshot of table](http://s1240.photobucket.com/user/prasanna_mundas/media/IMG_20140508_194720170_zps5b8ff997.jpg.html)

Comment: I strongly recommend to use json for this. You can iterate over your table-rows an build an json-object. Then post this json-object via ajax - php can handle this. On view-site iterate over the json and build your table or use a plugin like dataTables.

Comment: Thank you,If you have reference link please put it here please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 jQuery datatables packages for Laravel (that i know of) which handle this kind of thing for you.  No need for HTML in AJAX responses.  Im using the one by Chumper and it makes things a lot easier.  You just need to provide the data in your controller or route, and add the helper to your view.

https://github.com/Chumper/Datatable

https://github.com/bllim/laravel4-datatables-package << (haven't worked with this one)